# Generating numbers until I get 7,17,26,28,31,32

Tags: python

I want a lottery number generator that generates numbers until I get 7,17,26,28,31,32. Please post the complete code, not just parts of it, because I'm a beginner Python programmer. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. Here's my code:

```
import random
def nums():
    a=random.randrange(1,6)
    b=random.randrange(1,9)
    c=random.randrange(1,9)
    d=[7,9]
    e=random.choice(d)
    f=random.randrange(8,16)
    g=random.randrange(8,16)
    if a+b+c+e+f+g<46:
        list=[a,b,c,e,f,g]
        random.shuffle(list)
        u=list[0]
        v=list[0]+list[1]
        w=v+list[2]
        x=w+list[3]
        y=x+list[4]
        z=y+list[5]
        print(u,v,w,x,y,z)
    else:
        print("-----------------")
    return
h=0
while(h<200):
    print(h,end='. ')
    nums()
    h=h+1
```

Comment: Make nums return the list that is created inside of it.  Then load a variable with nums in each iteration of the loop. ```nums = nums()```

Answer (score 1):

Your `nums` function does not return a value, so it implicitly returns a `None`
You would need to change it to return a list of numbers if you want to compare the output to a list of numbers.

Something along the lines of `return [u,v,w,x,y,z]`

Comment: Please post the complete code, not just parts of it, because I'm a beginner Python programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Your function would need to actually `return` (as opposed to `print`) a list in order for it to be compared with anything.

Comment: Please post the complete code, not just parts of it, because I'm a beginner Python programmer.

Comment: You won't ever get beyond that if you don't at least try to code the changes yourself.

Comment: Where did you put it?  In what way "it didn't work"?

Comment: At the end of my nums() function. The comparison nums()!=7,17,26,28,31,32 does not seem to work.

Comment: Have you verified that `nums` is returning *anything* yet?  What code are you using to test what it returns?  What makes you think it will randomly choose those numbers?

Comment: @yellowcab if you want in-depth help on becoming a better programmer, that is a righteous and honorable desire and I commend you for it. However, stackoverflow is not the place for that discussion. I suggest you try a more discussion-oriented forum like dreamincode.net where you will get the sort of help it sounds like you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, your function prints information out (to your terminal), but it doesn't `return` any data to the caller.

If you put this at the end of your `nums()` function:

```
return [u,v,w,x,y,z]
```

then the comparison in your main loop should work.

Comment: Please post the complete code, not just parts of it, because I'm a beginner Python programmer.